# Persistent variable in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm using a token based Oauth system(Identity 2.0) and I have a class that's inherited from RestSharp's RestClient that is instantiated in different controllers and within that class is all of my calls to my API.

Once my login function succeeds and returns a token, I want to save that token and when the next request comes for an API call I want it to be able to use that token in the header since all of my data sensitive parts of the API are wrapped in authorize tags.

```
public class ApiClient : RestClient
{
   private static string CurrentToken;

    public string Login(string username, string password)
    {
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("Token", Method.POST);

        string encodedBody = string.Format("grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}", username, password);
        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", encodedBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        request.AddParameter("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", ParameterType.HttpHeader);

        IRestResponse response = base.Execute(request);

        LoginTokenResult result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginTokenResult>(response.Content);

        if (result.Error != null)
        {
            return result.Error;
        }

        CurrentToken = result.AccessToken;
    }
 }

public class LoginTokenResult
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return AccessToken;
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "error")]
    public string Error { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "error_description")]
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Now this app will have multiple users simultaneously, and I was told that by declaring it as a static variable it would overwrite the first user's value when the second user logged on. I've also read that you shouldn't use session variables for this type of sensitive information (since it allows access to the data)

So ultimately what is the best approach to allow that token value to persist for each call while still staying secure.

Edit:
I did some research and I'm wondering if I can just use the identity 2.0 cookie with each request rather than store the token value itself. Any input as to how I could do such a thing?

Comment: An approach you could take. Create a database table with columns "Key" and "LoginToken". Now Store the key with encryption in the session. Now you know what their Login token is from the database.

Comment: The whole point is that they need the token to hit the database, so that doesn't really meet the criteria.

Comment: Are the users make the login via the same instance of the ApiClient?

Comment: Not necessarily. The login is made from an instance in the HomeController, and the next call could be from a different controller with it's own instantiated ApiClient.